# Unable to Migrate GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I click on Move, I only see the current organization as the target.

I have the following roles (same principal email in source and target):

Source organization:

```
Billing Account Administrator
Organization Administrator
Owner
Project Creator
Project IAM Admin
Project Mover
```

Source Project:

```
Organization Administrator
Owner
Project IAM Admin
Project Mover
```

Target Organization:

```
Billing Account Administrator
Organization Administrator
Organization Policy Administrator
Owner
Project Creator
Project IAM Admin
Project Mover
```

roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin enabled on both source and target organizations

constraints/resourcemanager.allowedExportDestinations in source organization is set to Enable All
constraints/resourcemanager.allowedImportSources in target organization is set to Enable All

Comment: have you tried to move the project using the gcloud command "gcloud beta projects move [Project-ID] --organization [ORG-ID]"

Comment: @SiegfredV. - That command does not support projects that are already part of an organization.

Comment: @John Hanley, Looks like another case where the documentation is wrong.  In https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#perform_migration it says "The following instructions are only for migrating a project from one organization resource to another organization resource" and next is that gcloud command.  Do you now of any place where it's documented that that command doesn't work on projects that are part of an organization?  I'd like to open a case to improve the documentation.

Comment: It is mentioned under migration. However, the wording is very confusing. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration **This only involves migrating projects from one organization resource to another. If you want to transfer Google Workspace domains between organization resources, reach out to your Support representative.**

Answer (score 1):

You can move a project between organization resources in the same organization.

Moving a project to a different organization requires Google Cloud Support to perform the move on your behalf. Google will move the projects out of the current organization. Those projects are now standalone (no parent organization). You will then move the standalone projects into the desired organization.

Comment: unfortunately the documentation doesn't mention this: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration.  Do you know if that is documented anywhere else?  I'd like to open a case for the documentation itself to be improved.

Comment: also, I know that logs on projects with no organization are stored at the project level, otherwise they're stored at the org level.  After migrating from no org to org, the BigQuery logs are no longer available (e.g., INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS).  Do you know when going from org-to no org (temporarily)-to a new org, would the logs be maintained?

Comment: and what types of logs does this apply to?

Comment: @user994165 - I do not know the details on how logs on managed during a move.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow the steps to migrate the project to no organization. I have provided you with the link for better understanding [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration). Also, you can follow the below steps.

Now the project migration has become a self service, and to proceed with the migration below roles should be available. Refer [documentation](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#permissions_move)

The project resource that you want to move is the parent resource, and should have a project mover role.

Permission needed  for resources that is moving “resourcemanager.projects.update” and permission required for a parent resource is “resourcemanager.projects.move”

On the destination side the following roles should be associated with user account,

If the destination resource is a folder then the role should be “resourcemanager.projects.move”

If the destination resource is a organization then the role should be “resourcemanager.projects.create”

Please find the documentation for your reference.

Since you mentioned that you have user id who has owner role which has both “resourcemanager.projects.move”
and “resourcemanager.projects.create” permissions already,  you can use below command to proceed with the organization movement,

gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID \  --organization ORGANIZATION_ID

This will resolve your issue .

Comment: the instructions say that a migration to no organization has to be done by a support representative and requires business justification.